# How can I pass a parameter into the Chrome Storage get function, and set that parameter as the key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

So I have this function that is supposed to return the saved value of the set key using the chrome storage API:

```
 function loadBtn(id) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    chrome.storage.sync.get([id], function(result) {
      resolve(result.id);
    });
  });
}
```

Basically, I am looking through all of the elements with the same class, and saving their background-color value, and the key is set as their ID. Heres what I mean (`favBtnBG` is just an RGB value):

```
$('.colorBtn').click(function() {
  let favBtnBG = await loadRbgVal();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ [id]: favBtnBG });
})
```

The problem is that when I try to call the `loadBtn` function, it returns undefined. Heres how I am calling it (the console logs out undefined)

```
$('.colorBtn').someListener(function() {
  highlightedRgbVal = await loadBtn($(this).attr('id'));
  console.log(highlightedRgbVal)
})
```

The way I see it, there could be two possible errors. The first would be that I am not setting the value correctly in the storage. I think that by using the brackets while setting the key, the value of the variable `id` is used as the key, rather than the string `id`, but please correct me if I am wrong.

The second possible error is that there is something wrong with my `loadBtn` function. The function was working before I started passing `id` into it, so I don't think that I am passing it in correctly.

With that being said, **how do I properly pass in a parameter to the `storage.sync.get()` function?**

Comment: AFAICT, all you need to fix is `resolve(result[id]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const id = 'valueOfID';
chrome.storage.sync.get([id], function(result) {
      console.log(result[id]);
});
```

In this case the value of id is substituted and if your storage look like this:

```
{
      valueOfID: 'whateveryousetit'
}
```

then you will log `whateveryousetit`.
If you simply want to read from the storage key id then:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(['id'], function(result) {
      console.log(result.id);
});
```

with this storage:

```
{
      id: 'yourvalue'
}
```

you will log `yourvalue`

I don't think you can combine async await and promises like this.
You could call your current load function like this:

```
loadBtn(id).then(idValueFromStorage) => {
   console.log(idValueFromStorage)
}
```

Personally, I think that creating promise wrappers for storage getting is pretty pointless.
You can make it pretty clean with this syntax:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(['yourStorageKey'], ({ yourStorageKey }) => {
    console.log(yourStorageKey);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using the dot notation instead of the bracket notation.